# I'm looking for an iPhone app to collect money (determine money goals)

Tags: iphone, applications

I wonder if there is an application (on iPhone) to determine money goals, for example I can set an aim "vacation on Hawaii - $5000" and see the progress from 0-100% after adding money.

Answer (score 1):

[Moneywell](http://nothirst.com/moneywell/iphone/) will look at what you are saving but shows the amount you have saved not the %age but you can set monthly/weekly budgets so that money is saved as you go along.

Comment: thx!,better, but still not I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I suppose **[Numbers](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/numbers/id361304891?mt=8)** would do the trick.

Comment: Numbers is a whole spreadsheet, I do not need a cow to drink a glass of milk ;)

Comment: I kinda except it would be too broad for your needs :) But you want something really specific and with Numbers you'll be able to manage many "goals" and more, since the app is very versatile. Anyway, worth a shot, maybe it'll help someone else. Hope you find the app you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mint's [budgeting features](https://www.mint.com/how-it-works/budgeting/) and [goal tracking](https://www.mint.com/how-it-works/goals/) would seem to do what you want, but I don't know if those features are carried over to the Mint [iPhone app](https://www.mint.com/how-it-works/anywhere/iphone/) to the point where you would be happy with them. It's free to sign up and for the mobile app, so you could try it out with only an investment of your time.

The Budget screen on the Mint website:

[image: Mint budget screen]